# Get Laravel Eloquent Collection from raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5 and I have a table of users, and two tables 'clients' and 'employes' which contain relations between users.

I would like to get all the clients and employees of the logged in user.

I have a raw query which works fine for that:

```
select users.* from clients, users
where clients.id_marchand = 8 and users.id = clients.id_client 
union 
select users.* from employes, users 
where employes.id_marchand = 8 and users.id = employes.id_employe 
order by `seen` asc, `created_at` desc limit 25 offset 0
```

Raw queries are returning an array, but I need to get an Eloquent Collection like :

```
return $this->model
->where(...)
->oldest('seen')
->latest()
->paginate($n);
```

I've tried a lot of different possibilities, but none of them is working...

Isn't there a way to do that with subqueries, or something else ?

Comment: I've tried some things like this :

`$liste_clients = $this->model
->with('clients')
->where('clients.id_marchand', '=', auth()->user()->id)
->where('users.id', '=', 'clients.id_client');

$liste_employes = $this->model
->with('employes')
->where('employes.id_marchand', '=', auth()->user()->id)
->where('users.id', '=', 'employes.id_employe')
->union($liste_clients);

return $liste_employes
->oldest('seen')
->latest()
->paginate($n);`

but my biggest problem is that i'm unable to select from several tables with query builder.

Answer (score 15):

You can just convert the query results to a collection using `collect()`

```
$users = \DB::select( "SELECT users.*
FROM clients,
       users
  WHERE clients.id_marchand = 8
    AND users.id = clients.id_client
  UNION
  SELECT users.*
  FROM employes,
       users
  WHERE employes.id_marchand = 8
    AND users.id = employes.id_employe
  ORDER BY `seen` ASC,
           `created_at` DESC LIMIT 25
  OFFSET 0" );

return collect( $users );
```

If more than the results being a collection of models you should use `hydrate()` (https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate)
For the example you provided, the code should be the following:

```
$users = \DB::select( "SELECT users.*
  FROM clients,
       users
  WHERE clients.id_marchand = 8
    AND users.id = clients.id_client
  UNION
  SELECT users.*
  FROM employes,
       users
  WHERE employes.id_marchand = 8
    AND users.id = employes.id_employe
  ORDER BY `seen` ASC,
           `created_at` DESC LIMIT 25
  OFFSET 0" );

return User::hydrate($users);
```

> Please just note that this method is slower and for a big set of data,
>   this approach could crash if the result is too big to get allocated in
>   ram

Answer (score 4):

You can run the query and then populate it into a model with `hydrate`:
eg:

```
$userData = DB::select('SELECT * FROM users ...');
$userModels = User::hydrate($userData);
```

Comment: What happens if there are new columns, how are hydrate gonna be used?